# UICollectionView Will Not append Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

When I add objects to my datasource, I am not able to see the added objects in my collectionview.

I am able to see in the numberOfItemsForSection increment in value, but the corresponding cells do not display the objects. The indexpath.row does not exceed its original value that I set before.
HALP.

Comment: If you want some help. Help the people willing to help and spend 5 minutes posting some code. Chances are, it'll take the person answering your question equally as long.

Comment: Do you execute the 'reload' action when you add objects to the datasource?